# Knowing $a|bx$ can we conclude that $\frac{a}{gcd(a,b)}|\frac{bx}{gcd(a,b)}$

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

<strike>Knowing $a|b$ can we conclude that $\frac{a}{gcd(a,b)}|\frac{b}{gcd(a,b)}$?</strike>

My apologies the thing I was actually looking for was actually if we have $a|bx$ can we conclude that $\frac{a}{gcd(a,b)}|\frac{bx}{gcd(a,b)}$ I thought for a moment $x$ didn't matter

Comment: $a|b$ implies $gcd(a,b)=a$ (well, assuming they're both positive integers)

Comment: Big hint: if $a|b$, what is $\gcd(a,b)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  $a|b$ means that gcd$(a,b)=a$ and $\frac a{\text{gcd}(a,b)}=1$ and $1|k$ for all nonzero $k$.

Based on the edit, we have $a=u\cdot \text{gcd}(a,b),\ b=v\cdot \text{gcd}(a,b)$, so given $a\mid bx$ we get

$$u\cdot \text{gcd}(a,b)\mid v\cdot \text{gcd}(a,b)\cdot x$$

so there exists $m$ such that

$$u\cdot \text{gcd}(a,b)\cdot m= v\cdot \text{gcd}(a,b)\cdot x$$

and dividing by $\text{gcd}(a,b)$ yields $u\cdot m=v\cdot x$ and so $u\mid v\cdot x$ and thus

$$\frac a{\text{gcd}(a,b)}\left.\right| \frac b{\text{gcd}(a,b)}\cdot x$$